# VIM: Replace function call without the arguments

Tags: regex, vim, replace

how can i search and replace a function call, but without the arguments of the function?

For short, i will search and replace from `foobar(arg1, arg2)` to `foobar: arg1, arg2;`

My goal is to keep  the `arg1, arg2`.

How can i solve this? Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Insert a line at the top of the file - we'll write a macro here. (That's the letter O, not a zero.)

```
ggO
```

Instructions for searching for a string of word-characters followed by an open paren, and leave the cursor at the end of the match

```
/\w*(/e<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-M>
```

Then we'd go to the matching parenthesis and replace it with a semicolon

```
%r;
```

Jump back to the other parenthesis (ctrl-letter O again, not zero)

```
<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-O>
```

Replace this parenthesis with `:`

```
s:<Space><Ctrl-V><Esc>
```

Then execute this macro again (assuming it is in the `q` register)

```
@q
```

Our macro is done, exit insert mode (your line should read: `/\w*(/e^M%r;^Os: ^[@q` now)

```
<Esc>
```

Pull the line into the `q` register (which also removes it from the current file, returning your file to its previous pristine state)

```
"qdd
```

Finally, the Big Moment: execute the recursive macro we've built in the `@q` register, which will transform the whole file.

```
@q
```

**BENEFITS**: it handles nested functions correctly, since it is not relying on the regular expressions that have trouble capturing parenthesis matching. Instead we rely on the `%` command to match parentheses.

Demo:

```
foo(bar, baz)
foo(foo(bar), baz(), foo(foo, foo, foo))
foo(bar(baz()))
```

turns into

```
foo: bar, baz;
foo: foo: bar;, baz: ;, foo: foo, foo, foo;;
foo: bar: baz: ;;;
```

**EDIT**: typo (`\w`, not `\e` in search).

Answer (score 3):

Use following command:

```
:%s/\v(\w+)\(([^()]*)\)/\1: \2;/g
```

**NOTE** This does not work if there nested function call.

See [a demo](http://asciinema.org/a/7684).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach that works with arbitrarily named arguments:

```
:%s/\(\<foobar\)(\(.*\))/\1: \2;/g
```

Basically, it *captures* (via `\(...\)`) the function name and the arguments (without the parentheses), and then re-assembles it in a `:substitute` command. The `\<` asserts a *keyword boundary*, so that it doesn't match `myfoobar(`.

#### Caveats

Note that regular expressions are limited in their ability to parse programming language constructs; a proper refactoring tool allows more precise and safer modifications.

One problem in your example is how to deal with the arguments; I've chosen a *greedy match* (`.*`), but this would improperly handle a construct like `foobar(arg1, arg2); baz(arg3, arg4)`. A non-greedy match (`.\{-}` in Vim), on the other hand, would fail to capture embedded sub-calls like `foobar(hostname(), arg2)`. Writing a regular expression to handle all cases is close to impossible, so it's your responsibility to use this wisely (maybe by adding the `c` flag to the `:substitute` command and acknowledging each replacement manually).

Comment: Thanks. Sadly this don't solve a problem, with the arguments. There are not fix. I probably expressed myself wrong, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You may search for

```
(foobar)(\()(arg1, arg2)(\))
```

and replace it with

```
\1: \3;
```

([demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xL3jM4))

So, in VIM it may be something like

```
:s/(foobar)(\()(arg1, arg2)(\))/\1: \3;/g
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly this don't solve a problem, with the arguments. There are not fix.